# Thread freezes only the first time in while loop

Tags: multithreading, audio, input, chatbot, python-multithreading

So, I'm a beginner with Threads. On the other hand, this program is kind of huge, but I'll try to put only the essential stuff.

In summary, I have a queue in a Thread that plays audio files appended to the queue, then an initial input(), after that is a while loop where inside I append the first entry, and next I have an input().

My problem is that the thread freezes in the loop at the input() line code, but only the first time. When I type the first entry in the input() outside the while, the entry is successfully queued inside the while (before playing the audio file). But, when the loop reaches the input() line, the thread that attempts to play the audio files just freezes until I type the second entry. Then, the audio file is played as it would, and the second entry is queued and played too (while the loop continues with the next input()). From here, the loop and the Thread work as they should. Letting me type entries without waiting for the audio files being played and the audio files being played in the background.

Just to mention it, I do not think it only does the queue thread freeze, but I think the whole code freezes until the second entry is typed.

In other words, the code freezes in the first loop at the input(), and waits for the input to continue. But, the rest of the loops work as they should, with the queue working in the background receiving entries, and playing files while the main code just asks for inputs.

These aren't the exact functions, but have the same essence (also I tested them and they have the same bug):

main.py

```py
play_queue = []

def read_queue():
    while True:
        if len(play_queue) != 0:  # Whether is something in the queue
            print("Getting file...")
            file = play_queue[0]
            print("Calling play function...")
            play(file, SPEAKERS_ID)
            print("Removing from queue...")
            play_queue.pop(0)  # Removes the audio from the queue
        else:  # Whether the queue is empty
            sleep(0.5)
            print("Empty queue")


def play(filename, device_id):
    print("Starting play function...")
    try:
        print("Reading file")  # This is the last print before the Thread (or the code) freezes and the only way to make it continue is typing another input (just the first time)
        data, fs = sf.read(filename, dtype='float32')  # Gets the audio file info.
        print("File read")
        print("Playing audio...")
        sd.play(data, fs, device=device_id)  # Plays the audio file
        sd.wait()
        print("Fin del audio.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Un error desconocido ha ocurrido: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=read_queue, daemon=True).start()  # This is the thread that reads the queue

    song = input("Prompt: ")  # Asks for the first input
    while song.lower() != 'exit':
        read_queue.append(song)
        song = input("Prompt: ")  # Second and subsequent inputs (freezes here the first time)
```

This is my first project using Threads and also my first time using stack overflow LUL. I would be very grateful to anyone who could help me.

Some notes:

- I think it's kind of obvious, but I'm pretty new on programming. I'm sorry if some of the code looks like a mess.
- English isn't my native language. I apologize if something is poorly written or cannot be understood. I'd try my best to tell my problem. (I also changed some print texts to English to be easier to read).
- Oh, and sorry for the huge text. The problem is too specific and I tried to explain it as well as I could in order to clarify everything about it.

Things I've tried:
I tried making a lot of print() in order to find the problem. I tried executing the play() function on a Thread, but that kind of breaks the while loop, so I had to make a lot of changes in order to work (and it didn't solve it, either). I tried to ask ChatGPT hahaha (didn't work). Tried to change the place of the first input() (I don't know why, I think I'm just trying everything). I tried to constantly print the queue content, which only confirmed that the audio is appended to the queue, but for some reason, the Thread freezes at half of the play() function. Also tried to relax and find the solution later (yeah, didn't work at all LMAO).

Changelog:
Edited the whole post and the code. Apparently, there were some incompatibility issues between libraries (? that fixed themselves after importing another library to the code (yes, just how it sounds... or reads? lmao). The complete code is huge, no cap. But even the first code that I posted was big, so I just removed it and posted a smaller example that had the exact same bug. I hope this smaller and more concise version helps someone who encounters the same bug. For now, I only can say to import the library I put in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so... for some reason importing lingua library fixed it (?
(Yeah, I'm also confused).
Apparently it was a problem with the input() and, I think, an incompatibility among packages. So impoting lingua library just solved the incompatibility (? maybe.

Just posting if someone else get the same problem using Threads, input() and a while loop. Hoping it solves the problem.

Btw, yeah it's literally importing the library. If I remove the `from lingua import Language, LanguageDetectorBuilder` line, the bug is there. If I add it, the bug disappears.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34727634)

Comment: @andygavin: This doesn't appear to be additional information, but rather a proposed solution to the problem.

Comment: @JeremyCaney it's phrased as if I import lingua then it magically works, but with a lot of uncertainty as to why. An answer would state what the issue is with input. I'd expect either the answer to be more complete or this to be as part of the question.

Comment: @andygavin: Adding more information, or better isolating the specific incompatibility, would certainly be ideal, but isn’t necessary. Editing their question would be inappropriate here since this solved their problem. (Though editing their _question_ to focus on the core issue without extraneous code would be welcome.) Remember, deletion is for posts that make no effort to answer the question, but generally not simply for lower quality posts (despite the confusing name) ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/3025856)).

Comment: @andygavin But it's literally that. If I import lingua, it just works... I don't know why and what was the incompatibility. I'm kinda new at programming in Python, so I don't know how to find out the incompatibility. I would like to make a more complete answer, but that's literally everything I know about the solution. I just put in-hold that part of the code and continued making another part (file), then because of testing I noticed the bug disappeared when imported lingua, so I tried importing it in the other parts of the code and it just worked. The bug disappeared. Idk why.

Comment: @JeremyCaney well, that's right. I could put an smaller but concise code. It's just that I was so stressed in the moment that I posted almost a big part of the code because I wasn't able to find out the problem after days of continuous searching and testing. But now I think I'm able to do it more focused on the core issue. I'm going to do it today.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I don't think your assertion is correct. The question is a narrative of the speculative things that were tried to solve an issue.  The question should not: contain a  lot of speculation and would be much better without the experience.  I assert this isn't much of an answer is doesn't address some of the speculation in the question.  If the question were why doesn't this code work, then perhaps.  But it's a question about threads so it should include an answer about the threading or be reworded to just be a question on how to get the code working.

Comment: @andygavin: It might be worth voicing your concerns on meta, and especially if you feel that this question and/or answer should not be permitted.